# How to mockk() class with val

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

```
class Totals {
    val subTotals = mutableMapOf<String, SubTotals >()
}
data class SubTotals(
    val x: Int = 0, 
    val y: Int = 0
)
```

```
every { getTotals() } returns Totals(
      subTotals = mutableMapOf("Bag" to SubTotals(10, 100)))
```

When I try to mockk() Totals I get *cannot find a parameter with this name 'subTotals'*

Answer (score 1):

You should move subTotals to constructor

From

```kotlin
class Totals {
    val subTotals = mutableMapOf<String, SubTotals>()
}
```

to

```kotlin
class Totals(
    val subTotals: MutableMap<String, SubTotals> = mutableMapOf()
)
```